# fail azure sso authentication

Tags: angular, azure, single-sign-on

I am trying to authenticate with azure SSO through angular but I am getting this error

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Seamless single sign on failed for
> the user. This can happen if the user is unable to access on premises
> AD or intranet zone is not configured correctly

it randomly works but only like 10% of the time, the rest of the trial fails for the above error
any ideas

my reference is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code

Comment: update it looks like its working on IE and not chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was fixed by fixing my browser language to be according to my location